# Mongoose Error: "Cast to Array failed for value "...."

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Am getting this error when trying to create  (insert) an object that contains an array.

If i remove the "parking" field containing the array everything works!
but with it, it doesn't work, i've tried everything i could possibly  think of, but i still dont understand what causes this error.

Apparently there is a problem casting to an array, but its already an arry, i dont understand.

Sample object that i insert:

```
{
   "uid": "54654654",
   "firstName": "loo",
   "lastName": "laa",
   "to": "ok",
   "seat_no": "15",
   "date_departure": "2017-12-31T18:30:00.000Z",
   "date_return": "2017-12-31T18:30:00.000Z",
   "traveller": "svsbsf",
   "parking": [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "numberplate": "3554654",
         "brand": "bool",
         "model": "baa",
         "type": 1,
         "$$hashKey": "object:26"
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is the mongoose model

```
{
    uid: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    dob: Date,
    phone: String,
    address: String,
    profession: String,
    nationality: String,
    bloodgroup: String,

    parking: [ {
        numberplate: String,
        brand: String,
        model: String,
        type: String
    }],
```

And i get this error:

```
     "errors": {
      "parking": {
         "message": "Cast to Array failed for value \"[ { numberplate: '', brand: '', model: '', type: '' },\n  { numberplate: '', brand: '', model: '', type: '' } ]\" at path \"parking\"",
         "name": "CastError",
         "stringValue": "\"[ { numberplate: '', brand: '', model: '', type: '' },\n  { numberplate: '', brand: '', model: '', type: '' } ]\"",
         "kind": "Array",
         "value": [
            {
               "numberplate": "",
               "brand": "",
               "model": "",
               "type": ""
            },
            {
               "numberplate": "",
               "brand": "",
               "model": "",
               "type": ""
            }
         ],
         "path": "parking",
         "reason": {
            "message": "Cast to string failed for value \"{ numberplate: '', brand: '', model: '', type: '' }\" at path \"parking\"",
            "name": "CastError",
            "stringValue": "\"{ numberplate: '', brand: '', model: '', type: '' }\"",
            "kind": "string",
            "value": {
               "numberplate": "",
               "brand": "",
               "model": "",
               "type": ""
            },
            "path": "parking"
         }
      }
   },
   "_message": "Ticket validation failed",
   "message": "Ticket validation failed: parking: Cast to Array failed for value \"[ { numberplate: '', brand: '', model: '', type: '' },\n  { numberplate: '', brand: '', model: '', type: '' } ]\" at path \"parking\"",
   "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to define the array item as a separate schema and then define your `parking` field as below:

```
{
    uid: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    dob: Date,
    phone: String,
    address: String,
    profession: String,
    nationality: String,
    bloodgroup: String,
    parking: [ArrayItemTypeYouDefined]
}
```

For more information see [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

Comment: @can could you please tell me how to make required:true for an array?

Comment: @darshanan you need to explicitly define the type instead of just wrapping it with brackets as below:

var ToyBoxSchema = new Schema({
  toys: {
    type: [ToySchema],
    required: true
  }
});

Answer (score 0):

Note that Mongoose might ALSO throw this error when something goes wrong when it is casting individual items inside the Array.

In my case i was using correct subschemas

```
nestedSchema = Schema({label:String, count:{type:Number, default:Symbol()});
actualSchema = Schema({ items:[nestedSchema] });

modalOfActual.items.push({label:'hello'});
```

validation will fail because the item inside it does not validate!!!! NOTHING will ever match the default. In my case it was a default using a Symbol , but it could be anything...