# making post request giving Cast to Array failed for value

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

this is my classes schema which has batches field. when I am making a post to request in postman in form-data with `Key=batches` and `value=[{startDate:"14-july",endDate:"14-july",time:"2:00AM"}]` I am getting error  `Classes validation failed: batches: Cast to Array failed for value "[{startDate:"14-july",endDate:"14-july",time:"2:00AM"}]" at path "batches"`

```
export const ClassesSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    classType: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      enum: classType,
      default: "Private",
    },

    topic: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    price: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    meetingLink: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    markets: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
    },
    batches: [
      {
        startDate: {
          type: String,
        },
        endDate: {
          type: String,
        },
        time: {
          type: String,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

when i am making a post to request in postman in form-data with `Key=batches` and `value=[{startDate:"14-july",endDate:"14-july",time:"2:00AM"}]` I am getting error  `Classes validation failed: batches: Cast to Array failed for value "[{startDate:"14-july",endDate:"14-july",time:"2:00AM"}]" at path "batches"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose Error: "Cast to Array failed for value "...."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566796/mongoose-error-cast-to-array-failed-for-value)